# How to extract the root domain

Tags: javascript

I used this formula to extract the root domain:

```
=regexextract(regexreplace(regexreplace(A1, "^[^/]//", ""), "/.$", ""), "[^.]+.[^.]+$")
```

however, whenever I enter a URL with an additional extension like `www.countryandtownhouse.co.uk`

the result will return `co.uk` instead of returning `countryandtownhouse.co.uk`

How should I fix this? Many thanks. :)

Comment: Take a look at [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Comment: FYI the "additional extension" is called a top level domain [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain)

Comment: How do you define "the root domain"? How about cases like `mail.google.com` or `someuser.github.io`? You will need a better definition before you can code it up.

Comment: ```window.location``` Object contains values like, ```host```, ```origin```, ```hostname``` etc. to understand or check you can just console it in the browser.

Comment: @Zain & Jordi - How does Location help solve this problem? It'll just tell you that the host is `www.countryandtownhouse.co.uk`, not which part of that is the "root domain" (by whatever definition the OP wants to use).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is really only possible using the list of eTLDs from the [public suffix list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Suffix_List), which changes regularly. What you're trying to do (it seems) is identify the level in that full host name that gets you to the end provider of the content of that site. You can't do that just with text processing, because as you've seen, the number of dots doesn't help you do that. Aside from the fact that the level you can register a domain varies (you can register `___.com`, but not `___.uk`, just `___.co.uk` or `___.org.uk`, etc.). But it goes further than that: Some companies (not registrars) let people use subdomains on their domains (examples: `___.github.io`, `___.dh.bytemark.co.uk`, ...).

That's why the public suffix list exists, so browsers can identify the point where the controlling entity is determined, for the purposes of displaying identifying information in the address bar, limiting cookies, etc.

So to do this for a given hostname, you'd:

1. Download the list (caching it as appropriate); you'll probably need to cache it on your server or use a proxy of some kind, because the list isn't served with CORS headers
2. Identify the maximum-length suffix that applies (in this case, `.co.uk`)
3. Take the suffix plus one further level: `countryandtownhouse.co.uk`

Live Example:

```js
let list = null;
let btn = document.getElementById("btn-check");
let txt = document.getElementById("txt-hostname");
btn.disabled = true;

console.log("Loading list...");
getPublicSuffixList()
.then(() => {
    console.log("Got list; ready to find roots");
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let hostname = txt.value;
        let index = hostname.indexOf("//");
        if (index !== -1) {
            hostname = hostname.substring(index + 2);
        }
        index = hostname.indexOf("/");
        if (index !== -1) {
            hostname = hostname.substring(0, index);
        }
        showRoot(hostname);
    });
    btn.disabled = false;
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});

function getPublicSuffixList() {
    // NOTE: USING cors-anywhere IS PURELY FOR THE PURPOSES OF DEMONSTRATING
    // THE CODE ON STACK OVERFLOW. DON'T USE IT IN PRODUCTION!!!!
    return fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat")
        .then(res => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
            }
            return res.text();
        })
        .then(data => 
            // Split it into lines
            data.split(/\r?\n/)
            // Add dots to the data lines, convert comments and blanks to nulls
            .map(line => {
                line = line.trim();
                return (line && !line.startsWith("//")) ? `.${line}` : null;
            })
            // Filter out the nulls
            .filter(Boolean)
            // Sort longest first
            .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
        );
}

function findRoot(hostname) {
    for (const entry of list) {
        if (hostname.endsWith(entry)) {
            // Found the suffix, find out how many segments to keep (note: since we added a `.`
            // at the beginning of the entries on the list, it's the same as the number of
            // segments in the entry we matched
            const segmentCount = entry.split(".").length;
            // Get the segments of this hostname
            const segments = hostname.split(".");
            // Return just the ones we need
            return segments.slice(-segmentCount).join(".");
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function showRoot(hostname) {
    const root = findRoot(hostname);
    console.log(`${hostname} => ${root}`);
}

(async () => {
    list = await getPublicSuffixList();
    console.log(findRootDomain("www.countryandtownhouse.co.uk"));
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt-hostname" value="www.countryandtownhouse.co.uk">
<input type="button" id="btn-check" value="Check" disabled>
<p>Examples to try:</p>
<ul>
<li><code>www.countryandtownhouse.co.uk</code></li>
<li><code>www.foo.github.io</code></li>
<li><code>foo.github.io</code></li>
</ul>
```

Please note that the example isn't a complete, robust, production-ready solution. It's an *example*, a sketch of the general form of a solution. For instance, it should probably apply some heuristics if it doesn't find a suffix match.